# terminate called without an active exception | return false if !isdigit()

Tags: c++

When giving any non-integer number as input program is terminated. Is there any fix?

Getting called here (isWholeNumber)

```
    try{
        cout << "Please enter option (1-" << NUMBER_OF_OPTIONS << "): ";
        getline(cin, input);

        userOption = stoi(input);

        if(!helper.isWholeNumber(input)) { throw; }
        
    }
    catch(...){
        cout << "Error: Input Invalid" << endl;
        helper.pressEnterToContinue();
        return false;
    }
```

Implementation

```
bool Helper::isWholeNumber(const string &stringToCheck) const
{
    for(int i = 0; i < stringToCheck.length(); i++){
        if(!isdigit(stringToCheck[i])){ 
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Error Message

> terminate called without an active exception

Terminates program as well

```
bool Helper::isWholeNumber(const string &stringToCheck) const
{
    bool success = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < stringToCheck.length(); i++){
        if(!isdigit(stringToCheck[i])){ 
            success = false;
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: Read [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) it already does its own validation and throws an exception if input is incorrect. Also do not use `catch(...)` but  `catch(const std::exception& e)` you can then print the `e.what()` to get more info

Comment: What is the point of `try`/`throw`/`catch` here? It doesn't make sense to throw an exception and then immediately catch it in the enclosing scope. You could just put the `catch` contents into the `if`'s block instead. No exception handling required.

Comment: And `throw` needs an operand which is the exception that you want to throw. `throw` without an operand has a different meaning: It rethrows an earlier exception, which is not what you want to do here (and can't because there is no earlier exception).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool Matrices::getUserOptionInput(int &userOption)
{
    string input = "";

    cout << "Please enter option (1-" << NUMBER_OF_OPTIONS << "): ";
    getline(cin, input);

    if(input.length() > 0){
        if(helper.isWholeNumber(input)){
            userOption = stoi(input);
            return true;
        }
    }

    cout << "Error: Invalid Input" << endl;
    helper.pressEnterToContinue();

    return false;
}
```